# Launch notification activity from another package

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I want to set the intent to my MainActivity.class which is in a different package than my Notification.class. I tried using ComponentName but still gives me NULL Pointer Exception for addParentStack(componentName) and the NotificationManager line. `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference`

```
package com.workdemos.preference;

public class Notification extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void pushNotification() {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.workdemos.user", "MainActivity");

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("New News")
                .setContentText("new news found in your preferred city");

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.setComponent(componentName);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(componentName);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried send the context from the caller class which is in the same package of MainActivity.class.

```
 public void pushNotification(Context context) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("New News")
            .setContentText("new news found in your preferred city");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context, MainActivity.class));
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getBaseContext());
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

This way it passed the lines which gave me errors before. But it did not pass addParentStack(MainActivity.class). It still gives me the same error at that line.

Comment: Try with changing like `ComponentName("com.workdemos.user", "com.workdemos.user.MainActivity");`. Add your full path before MainActivity.

Comment: I did. Still the same.

Comment: Is `"com.workdemos.user"` your application package name?

Comment: application package is com.workdemos then I have multiple packages (user, preferences, models, news). The MainActivity in user and Notification in preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to make this work by creating a constructor to set the context passed to it at the instance initiation line.

```
public class Notification {

    private Context context;

    public Notification(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void pushNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("New News")
                .setContentText("new news found in your preferred city");

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context, MainActivity.class));

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(new ComponentName(context, MainActivity.class));
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ComponentName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html#ComponentName(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) has a constructor that takes a context and class as parameters. You can use it to get the ComponentName.

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: I used ComponentName with package and class because this one using context did not work

Comment: What was the issue that you had while using this approach?

Comment: getContext() gave me error so I used getBaseContext() which gave me (java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference) error at this line you suggested